# Why a set that is subset/equal to infinite set isn't infinite? (by definition)

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I searched but couldn't really find an answer for that, so sorry if its a duplicate or anything else.

My question is why a set, for example A, that has a subset/equal set which is infinite(N for example), isn't infinite by definition?
The formal definition for an infinite set is "A set is infinite if and only if for every natural number the set has a subset whose cardinality is that natural number."

It makes sense of course, and its easy to prove that A is also infinite, but then why wouldn't N ⊆ A also mean that A is infinite *by definition*? Is there an opposite example when it doesn't happen? I'm not very familiar with math definitions in english, so sorry if I wrote something wrong. Thanks.

Edit - @Asaf Karagila answered it perfectly. Thanks for the replies.

Comment: You can't use the word "infinite set" in the definition of an infinite set. That makes no sense.

Comment: What definition are you proposing?  "A set is infinite if it contains an infinite subset" does not make any sense.

Comment: Where did you get that definition? Also, definitions are most of the time arbitrary, they are good because they are useful in the sense they give the same consequences. For example, you can define an odd number as an even number plus one, or as an odd number minus one. By the first definition, $2x-1$ is not an odd immediately by definition, but this is fine because you can proof that it is one by using the axioms.

Comment: @lulu: From the question: "The formal definition for an infinite set is "A set is infinite if and only if for every natural number the set has a subset whose cardinality is that natural number."

Comment: @lulu After reading Asaf's answer I understand that for the OP infinite means "not finite".

Comment: @Yanko: No, that is not the definition the OP quotes in the question.

Comment: @HenningMakholm  Yes...but I thought the OP was objecting to that definition.  I suppose one could say "a set is infinite iff it has a subset which is isomorphic to the integers."  Seems awkward, though.

Comment: @HenningMakholm as I understand it, he quotes the definition, and then he said "it makes sense of course, and its easy to prove that A is also infinite" I believe that now when he says infinite he means not-finite.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. A set with an infinite subset is infinite. But this is not "by definition", but rather a theorem (or a proposition).

In mathematics we have definitions, and we have consequences. The definition of "an infinite set" should not refer to "infinite subsets". In fact, the standard definition of "infinite" is simply "not finite".

But we can prove that $X$ is infinite if and only if it has arbitrarily large finite sets. And then we can easily prove that if $X$ is infinite and $X\subseteq Y$, then $Y$ is infinite.

The thing is that when you say "this holds *by definition*", then you mean that this is the literal definition (perhaps with a minor and obvious modification). Whereas the definition of an infinite set is *not* that $\Bbb N$ is a subset of that set, or so on.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I did not mean that the definition for an infinite set should be that way, but in a lot of aspects there are many sentences for different cases. If for example someone told you to prove that N ⊆ A, you'd need to prove it in a way(which again, is not very hard), but if N is an infinite set, why wouldn't A considered an infinite set as well without the need for deeper prove? (hope its understanble). Thanks :)

Comment: If I am writing a research paper, I wouldn't think twice. Yes, $\Bbb N\subseteq A$ immediately implies that $A$ is infinite, case closed. If I am proving something to a classroom full of freshmen who never saw mathematics before, then I will absolutely prove this statement in details.

Comment: I see, Its just that I'm taking a math course atm, and they gave this question that appeared in one of the tests, there are many sentences similar to "if X then Y", and it didn't really made sense to me. Again, obviously its not something hard to prove, but it just feels weird to me that you actually need to prove it instead of simply having that sentence. But as you explained, that's just part of the course I guess, so its understandable. Thanks for the reply :)

Comment: If something is not hard to prove, that means you shouldn't have a hard time proving it. But one of the harder things in freshmen mathematics is understanding *what* is the statement that you even need to prove. For that kind of case, this question is perfect.

Answer (score 0):

So your definition of an infinite set would be

> A set is infinite if it contains an infinite subset.

This definition cannot be used to prove that any set is infinite. For example, we cannot prove that $\mathbb N$ is infinite, because to prove it is infinite, we need to find an infinite subset of $\mathbb N$. Ok, maybe $A_1=\mathbb N\setminus\{1\}$?

But how can we prove $A_1$ is infinite? Well, we have to find $A_2$, an infinite subset of $A_1$. And how can we prove $A_2$ is infinite? Well, by finding some subset $A_3$ of $A_2$ which is infinite. OK, but how do we prove $A_3$ is infinite? $\color{red}{\text{and on, and on, and on...}}$

Comment: No, the question contains a precise definition: _The formal definition for an infinite set is "A set is infinite if and only if for every natural number the set has a subset whose cardinality is that natural number."_ The OP merely appears to be confused about the difference between saying "this is so by definition" and "this is so as a consequence of the definition".